# Add object end of the array

Tags: java, arrays

Firstly, Hi everyone that read this topic. I have to add an object to end of array. For instance in ***(public C(int,int,int) method)*** I have to extend array ***"array2"*** and ***array2*** have two object for ***(A.B b1 = a1.new B();)***, have one object for ***(A.B b2 = a1.new B();)***.  
How can I add object?  
Thanks everyone very much.  
The following code is in test class

```
<pre>public class Test{

public static void main(String[] args) {
      A a1 = new A();
      A.B b1 = a1.new B();
      A.B b2 = a1.new B();
      A.B.C c1 = b1.new C();
      A.B.C c2 = b1.new C ();
      A.B.C c3 = b2.new C();}}
//And the other class that following
<pre>public class A{
    B [] array1;
    class B{
      C [] array2;
     class C{
       private int x;
       private int y;
       private int z;

      //For each creating C object, array "array2" must be extended.
      //add new C to end of array,How can I do?
      public C(int x, int y, int z){
      super();
      this.x =x;
      this.y=y;
      this.z=z;
   }
}
            //for each creating B object, array "array1" must be extended.
            //and add new B to end of array,How can I do that?
            public B() {
            super();
            array2 = new C[0];
   }}

      public A() {
        super();
        array1 = new B[0];
    }}
```

Comment: You can't. Arrays have a fixed size. You'll need to either create a new Array size is currentSize + 1, and copy your data, or use a List.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Java, arrays have a static size, meaning that once initialized, you cannot change the size.

What you *could* do, would be to create a new array which will be of size `n + m`, where `n` is the *current* size of the array and `m` is the amount of items you would like to add. You could then insert the new elements where you would like and use something like [`System.arrayCopy(Object src, int srcPos, Object dest, int destPos, int length)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy-java.lang.Object-int-java.lang.Object-int-int-) to move in your previous elements.

That being said, an easier approach would be to use an `ArrayList`, which provides a means to [`insert`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#add-int-E-), in a particular location of the array list.

Answer (score 1):

Is easier if you use an ArrayList instead.
Arrays have fixed size. The only way is to alocate a new array with greatter size.